# Multiple Kendo windows overlapping but text divs don't overlap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, kendo-ui, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a requirement to layout multiple Kendo windows (4 in a row and then next row and so on). The window, when closed, should cause the window right of it to be shifted left.

I am using Bootstrap 3.

This works perfectly fine with 6 divs placed in the same manner. The delete button in the code below removes one div at a time and the divs shift.

Problem with the Window inside the divs :

1) the 5th window overlaps the 1st window whereas it should be placed in the 2nd row.

2) The windows on the right don't shift when closed using the close button.

I see that the actual window control is created at the bottom in the html with the class `k-widget k-window`.
The div in the row class just houses the jQuery function to show the Window.

When I close the windows, the window destroys but the other windows left or top property doesn't change, thats why they remain in place instead of shifting left.

Code snippet :

```
<div class="row" id="partialWindows1">
    <div id="hello" class="col-md-3">    @(Html.Kendo().Window()
.Name("win1")
    .Title("Window1")
    .Content(@<text>
    </text>)
    .Draggable()
    .Width(150)
    .Height(60)
    .Events(e=> e.Deactivate("win_deac"))
          )
</div>
    <div class="col-md-3">@(Html.Kendo().Window()
.Name("win2")
    .Title("Window1")
    .Content(@<text>
    </text>)
    .Draggable()
    .Width(150)
    .Height(60)
    .Events(e=> e.Deactivate("win_deac"))
          )</div>
    <div class="col-md-3">@(Html.Kendo().Window()
.Name("win3")
    .Title("Window1")
    .Content(@<text>
    </text>)
    .Draggable()
    .Width(150)
    .Height(60)
    .Events(e=> e.Deactivate("win_deac"))
          )</div>
    <div class="col-md-3">@(Html.Kendo().Window()
.Name("win4")
    .Title("Window1")
    .Content(@<text>
    </text>)
    .Draggable()
    .Width(150)
    .Height(60)
    .Events(e=> e.Deactivate("win_deac"))
          )</div>
    <div class="col-md-3">@(Html.Kendo().Window()
.Name("win5")
    .Title("Window1")
    .Content(@<text>
    </text>)
    .Draggable()
    .Width(150)
    .Height(60)
    .Events(e=> e.Deactivate("win_deac"))
          )</div>
</div>

<br/>
<br/>

<div id="divDivs" class="row" style="margin-top: 100px">
    <div class="col-md-3">div1</div>
    <div class="col-md-3">div2</div>
    <div class="col-md-3">div3</div>
    <div class="col-md-3">div4</div>
    <div class="col-md-3">div5</div>
    <div class="col-md-3">div6</div>
</div>

<button id="btnDelete">Delete</button>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#btnDelete').on('click', function () {
            if ($('#divDivs div').length > 0)
                $('#divDivs div')[0].remove();
        });
    });

    function win_deac() {
        this.destroy();
    }
</script>
```

How should I fix this ? Thanks for looking...

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I solved this problem after knowing that there is an appendTo method on the Window widget. I have also added a nice animation when a window is deleted.

```
<div class="row">
    <div id="div1" class="col-md-3 atl-win">    @(Html.Kendo().Window()
.Name("win1")
    .Title("Window1")
    .Content(@<text>win1
    </text>)
    .Draggable()
    .Width(150)
    .Height(60)
    .AppendTo("#div1")
    .Events(e=> e.Deactivate("win_deac").Close("win_close"))
          )
</div>
    <div id="div2" class="col-md-3 atl-win">@(Html.Kendo().Window()
.Name("win2")
    .Title("Window2")
    .Content(@<text>win2
    </text>)
    .Draggable()
    .Width(150)
    .Height(60)
    .AppendTo("#div2")
    .Events(e=> e.Deactivate("win_deac").Close("win_close"))
          )</div>
    <div id="div3" class="col-md-3 atl-win">@(Html.Kendo().Window()
.Name("win3")
    .Title("Window3")
    .Content(@<text>win3
    </text>)
    .Draggable()
    .Width(150)
    .Height(60)
    .AppendTo("#div3")
    .Events(e=> e.Deactivate("win_deac").Close("win_close"))
          )</div>
    <div id="div4" class="col-md-3 atl-win">@(Html.Kendo().Window()
.Name("win4")
    .Title("Window4")
    .Content(@<text>win4
    </text>)
    .Draggable()
    .Width(150)
    .Height(60)
    .AppendTo("#div4")
    .Events(e=> e.Deactivate("win_deac").Close("win_close"))
          )</div>
    <div id="div5" class="col-md-3 atl-win">@(Html.Kendo().Window()
.Name("win5")
    .Title("Window5")
    .Content(@<text>win5
    </text>)
    .Draggable()
    .Width(150)
    .Height(60)
    .AppendTo("#div5")
    .Events(e=> e.Deactivate("win_deac").Close("win_close"))
          )</div>
</div>

<br/>
<br/>

<div id="divDivs" class="row" style="margin-top: 100px">
    <div class="col-md-3">div1</div>
    <div class="col-md-3">div2</div>
    <div class="col-md-3">div3</div>
    <div class="col-md-3">div4</div>
    <div class="col-md-3">div5</div>
    <div class="col-md-3">div6</div>
</div>

<button id="btnDelete">Delete</button>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#btnDelete').on('click', function () {
            if ($('#divDivs div').length > 0)
                $('#divDivs div')[0].remove();
        });
    });

    function win_deac() {
        this.destroy();
    }

    function win_close(e) {
        var $divRem = $(e.sender.options.appendTo);
        $divRem.hide(1000, function () { $divRem.remove(); });
    }
</script>
```

I Hope somebody may get some help with the answer.